# JavaScript - check Cisco Jabber user status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmpp

On my webpage I need to check if given user is available on Cisco Jabber Client. I have both number and user name.
I am already able to send chat messages and start voice conversations, but it would be nice to check if user is online, and for example show cool icon or something. 
Is there a simple way to do that in JavaScript/jQuery?

Or is it possible to check it by server side of web application (Spring/Java) and use AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

The service can be accessed using the REST Api's. Below URL can provide some information on this.

https://developer.cisco.com/site/collaboration/call-control/unified-presence/overview/presence-web-service/index.gsp

Honestly, I haven't tried this.

Comment: thanks. from what I have learned it looks like it is not an easy task. for more information I have to look trough documentation wich I have no access to. thanks anyway, I won't stop searching :)